# Stuck Working with Python List

Tags: python

I am new to python.  Started using it last week for the first time.  Until now, I have been quickly coming up to speed and making good progress coding.

I have a list variable (rawData) holding strings.

```
rawData[0:2]

['00:00:10.000000,     500.000000000,       5.00000000,    80.00,\n',
 '00:00:10.002667,     500.000000000,       5.00000000,    80.00,\n']
```

I am struggling to do the following, with the existing data:

```
rawData[0:2]

[['00:00:10.000000', '500.0', '5.0', '80.00'],
 ['00:00:10.002667', '500.0', '5.0', '80.00']]
```

Thanks for your time.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have this list

```
>>> L = ['00:00:10.000000,     500.000000000,       5.00000000,    80.00,\n',
...  '00:00:10.002667,     500.000000000,       5.00000000,    80.00,\n']
```

You could split each line into a list like this

```
>>> [item.split() for item in L]
[['00:00:10.000000,', '500.000000000,', '5.00000000,', '80.00,'], ['00:00:10.002667,', '500.000000000,', '5.00000000,', '80.00,']]
```

But you still need further processing, and since the processing is different for each field it's awkward and messy to try to do it all in a list comprehension. Instead, begin by writing a helper function. Let's call it "`process_item`"

```
>>> def process_item(item):
...     return item.split()
... 
>>> [process_item(item) for item in L]
[['00:00:10.000000,', '500.000000000,', '5.00000000,', '80.00,'], ['00:00:10.002667,', '500.000000000,', '5.00000000,', '80.00,']]
```

Now you're in a better position to add some code to `process_item` to handle your individual fields

```
>>> def process_item(item):
...     f1, f2, f3, f4 = item.split()
...     f1 = f1.rstrip(',')
...     f2 = f2.rstrip(',') # more code needed here
...     f3 = f3.rstrip(',') # more code needed here
...     f4 = f4.rstrip(',')
...     return [f1, f2, f3, f4]
```

Lets take a look how you might fix f2 and f3

```
>>> f2 = '500.000000000'
>>> f2[:f2.find('.')+2]
'500.0'
```

But you wouldn't want to do that if there was no `.` in f2

```
>>> f2 = '500'
>>> f2[:f2.find('.')+2]
'5'
```

So you'll need to test for that with an `if`. Put it all together now

```
>>> def process_item(item):
...     f1, f2, f3, f4 = item.split()
...     f1 = f1.rstrip(',')
...     f2 = f2.rstrip(',')
...     f3 = f3.rstrip(',')
...     f4 = f4.rstrip(',')
...     if '.' in f2:
...         f2 = f2[:f2.find('.')+2]
...     if '.' in f3:
...         f3 = f3[:f3.find('.')+2]
...     return [f1, f2, f3, f4]
... 
>>> [process_item(item) for item in L]
[['00:00:10.000000', '500.0', '5.0', '80.00'],
 ['00:00:10.002667', '500.0', '5.0', '80.00']]
```

Comment: Most comprehensive answer. Perhaps another option for standardizing the format of the strings of "integers" is to cast them to floats and use a string format specifier specifying the appropriate number of digits after the period to convert them back to the appropriate strings. Firstly, this will do away with the check for '.'. Second, if '.' is not found, it will add it in... if that is the intention of the OP. Third, you won't have to assume that there is going to be enough '0' after the period. The only assumption is that the last 3 strings can be cast to floats.

Answer (score 0):

`split` is a method possessed by all instances of `basestring` that will turn the string into a list of strings, splitting on a given character. `rstrip` will strip right-most occurrences of a character (remove trailing commas). Try something like this:

```
[ x.strip().rstrip(',').split(',') for x in rawData ]
```